# Llenar tabla Verticalmente en DOMPDF

Tags: php, sql, dompdf

quisiera llenar una tabla de la siguiente manera en DOMPDF.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente así sería como quiero llenar la información, primero el nombre de la marca, en la siguiente fila código 1 y código 2. Y después, se van colocando los código de cada marca. Si ya se lleno la columna pasa a la siguiente, justo donde termino. Así tienen que ser 4 columnas con las páginas que sean necesarias.

Para eso tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT marca, codigo1, codigo2 FROM marca
```

Lo único que no se hacer es como construir la forma de esa tabla. Es decir que se vaya llenando verticalmente y salte de una columna a otra, el resto lo puedo hacer. Como lo harían en DOMPDF? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es un trabajo de muchos iteradores,

Tienes que definir también un límite de filas incluso si deben pasar de página

Pero aquí un ejemplo

```
<?php

// Definir los arrays de marcas y códigos
$marcas = [
    ['Marca 1', 'cod 5 - cod 6', 'cod 2 - cod3'],
    ['Cod 1 - cod 2', 'Marca 2', 'Cod 4 - cod 5'],
    ['Cod 3 - cod 4', 'Cod 1 - cod 2', 'Cod 6 - cod 7']
];

// Obtener el número de filas y columnas de la tabla
$numFilas = count($marcas);
$numColumnas = count($marcas[0]);

// Imprimir la tabla
echo '<table border="1">';
for ($i = 0; $i < $numFilas; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($j = 0; $j < $numColumnas; $j++) {
        echo '<td>' . $marcas[$i][$j] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: Como podría convertir lo que devuelve la consulta a ese array de marcas

Comment: Ya lo hice, usted es dios.